# VBA: Set value of cell "Method 'Value' of object 'Range' failed"

Tags: excel, vba, office365

This is the first time I'm using VBA, so this problem might be silly, but I couldn't find any other mention to it.

Simply, I am trying to set the value of a cell programatically and VBA always crashes.

I can reproduce the problem with a simple line (inside a Worksheet - Change event)

```
Range("A1").Value = 1
```

The code works, cell A1 is set to 1, but an error "Method 'Value' of object 'Range' failed" is triggered. After that, excel becomes veery slow and glitchy, ends up crashing.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: See the linked question: you're causing the event to fire in an infinite loop.

Comment: Wow, makes sense. Wasn't seeing that, thank you!